# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'ToDoCtrl' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page like this using AngularJS 1.6.6:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>{{todo.user}}'s To-Do List</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Rest omitted for brevity -->
  </body>
</html>
```

`app.js` is literally nothing more than the following:

```
var model = {
  user: 'Adam',
  items: [{ action: 'Buy Flowers', done: false },
          { action: 'Get Shoes', done: false },
          { action: 'Collect Tickets', done: true },
          { action: 'Call Joe', done: false }]
};

var todoApp = angular.module('todoApp', []);

angular.module('todoApp').controller('ToDoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.todo = model;
});
```

Without fail I get the following error on the console:

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'ToDoCtrl' is not registered.
```

...despite very obviously having registered the controller. Not a good start for my AngularJS journey. If you want full code, you can get it here:

https://github.com/readyready15728/infernal-angularjs

Please don't request a fiddle or the like; I'm obviously not in the position to set one up for AngularJS yet.

Comment: can you try change <html ng-app lang="en"> to <html ng-app="todoApp" lang="en"> ?

Comment: Solved it. Looked everywhere but there.

Comment: glad it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all i recommend to read [angular-styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md).

If you have a design pattern you won't get an error like this. So you can use your code like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Test Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css"/>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="TodoController">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>{{vm.todo.user}}'s To-Do List</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="todo.controller.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Rest omitted for brevity -->
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', []);
})();
```

todo.controller.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('TodoController', TodoController);

    function TodoController($scope) { 
        var vm = this;
        vm.todo = {
                      user: 'Adam',
                      items: [{ action: 'Buy Flowers', done: false },
                              { action: 'Get Shoes', done: false },
                              { action: 'Collect Tickets', done: true },
                              { action: 'Call Joe', done: false }]};
    }

})();
```